# Use custom parameter annotations with RESTEasy

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
@Path("/test")
@GET 
public Response get(@Pageable(minSize = 5, maxSize = 10) Pageable pageable)
```

In Jersey, this can be achieved by implementing and registering a custom `ValueParamProvider`. How can this be done with RESTEasy?

RESTEasy's parameter injectors for the default `@*Param` annotations are defined by implementing the `ValueInjector` interface. This looks suitable for my usecase, but I am not sure how to register a new instance.

The default `@*Param` injectors are registered in the `InjectorFactoryImpl` class, but this does not look like something I can do.

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using? I also assume this is a cross-post of https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/discussions/3377.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I'm on 4.3.1.Final (API regarding this functionality remains unchanged in RESTEasy 6.x as far as I can see), and yes it is a cross-post.

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to do this. You could use `@Context` and a `ContextResolver`.